# Show only products the user did not order

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting data about products from 3 different tables and I want to show only products the user didn't order.

Table 1:

```
     Supplier
__________________
| id | name | .. |
|____|______|____|
| 1  | john | .. |
|____|______|____|
```

Table 2:

```
          Product
___________________________
| id | p_name| supplier_id |
|____|_______|_____________|
|  1 | phone |      1      |
|____|_______|_____________|
|  2 | watch |      1      |
|____|_______|_____________|
```

Table 3:

```
          Order
___________________________
| id |  p_id |  buyer_id   |
|____|_______|_____________|
|  1 |   1   |     10      |
|____|_______|_____________|
```

So in this case when the user visit the products page, I want to show the products he didn't order which is `watch` in this example.

My SQL query:

```
SELECT supplier.name, products.p_name FROM products 
INNER JOIN supplier ON supplier.id = product.supplier_id
INNER JOIN order ON product.id = order.p_id
```

I tried `LEFT JOIN order ON product.id != order.p_id` and `WHERE order.p_id IS NULL`, But no success.

So how to check if the user didn't order this product? Then show the rest of the products?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `WHERE product NOT IN` to exclude specific products, shown below.

```
SELECT supplier.name, products.p_name
FROM products
INNER JOIN supplier ON supplier.id = products.supplier_id
WHERE products.id NOT IN (
    SELECT p_id FROM order WHERE buyer_id = supplier.id
)
```

Within the `WHERE` statement, you select the product id's of all the orders from a specific user. By applying `NOT IN` all of these products will be excluded in your list.

Comment: @jarlh it does not, I removed them. It's a habit from using a table named "order".

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WHERE NOT EXISTS` statement for you case:

```
SELECT suppliers.name, products.name 
FROM products 
INNER JOIN suppliers ON suppliers.id = products.supplier_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT product_id FROM orders WHERE orders.product_id = products.id
);
```

[SQL fiddle here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=&sqlses=5a4dbdfd0bd6aa5e4573b9ab31b20d71&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

```
SELECT supplier.name, products.p_name
FROM product
INNER JOIN supplier ON supplier.id = product.supplier_id
LEFT JOIN order ON product.id = order.p_id
WHERE order.id IS NULL
```

You issue a `LEFT JOIN` against `order` to also get products without a match and you discard rows without matches with `order.id IS NULL`. There's also no need to discard duplicate rows because products that haven't been ordered will only appear once.

```
+---------+
|         |
|         |
|         |
| product +--------+
|         |        |
|         | order  |
|         |        |
+---------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an unusual schema; A supplier would not normally be an attribute of a 'products' table, and the details of the order would normally be held in a separate table from the orders - otherwise an order can only comprise one item, but anyway...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS suppliers;
CREATE TABLE suppliers
(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(12) UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO suppliers VALUES 
(1,'john');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS products;

CREATE TABLE products
(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,product_name VARCHAR(12) UNIQUE
,supplier_id INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO products VALUES 
(1,'phone',1),
(2,'watch',1);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS orders;

CREATE TABLE orders
(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,product_id INT NOT NULL
,buyer_id INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO orders VALUES
(1,1,10);
```

...

```
SELECT p.* 
  FROM products p 
  LEFT 
  JOIN orders o 
    ON o.product_id = p.id 
 WHERE o.id IS NULL;
+----+--------------+-------------+
| id | product_name | supplier_id |
+----+--------------+-------------+
|  2 | watch        |           1 |
+----+--------------+-------------+
```